# Can you remove an element from an array by placing it at the end of the array and decreasing the size of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
for(int i = 0; i < bag.length; i++)
      {
        if(bag[i].equals(a))
        {
            tmp = bag[i];
            bag[i] = bag[bag.length-1];
            bag[bag.length-1] = tmp;
            numElements--;
            break;
        }
}
```

The goal of this is to find an object in the array and then remove it? is it possible??

Answer (score 2):

Changing the length of an array is not possible. Recall that array is a static data structure whose size is determined before hand. Increasing or decreasing is not supported in this data structure. The fact that one has to increase or decrease the size depending on the usecase means that they have picked up the wrong data structure. They should perhaps go with an ArrayList.

Anyway, coming back to your question, you can simulate the 'size decrease' by maintaining a variable which you let track the array index and decrease the size of this variable. This lets you give the impression of shrinking the array.
The code you have provided does the same. Note however, that you should be using this modified index to track the contents of your array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < bag.length; i++)
      {
        if(bag[i].equals(a))
        {
            tmp = bag[i];
            bag[i] = bag[bag.length-1];
            bag[bag.length-1] = tmp;
            numElements--;
            break;
        }
}
```

Whenever a particular bag at a given index equals to the item under question i.e., 'a', we swap elements so that the current bag element to be removed moves to the last and also we reduce the size of our new index - numElements by 1 to simulate this.

If you have the full code with you, please consider adding the following snippet **at the end of that program** to understand this more:

```
// Simulation of the array shrinking.
for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
{    
    System.out.println( bag[i] );
}

// Movement of uninteresting elements to the end of the array.
for(int i = 0; i < bag.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println( bag[i] );
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning that using a list is usually the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the length of an array. You can overwrite the element you wish to remove with the last element of the array and then copy the first `bag.length - 1` elements of your array to a new array whose length is `bag.length - 1`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < bag.length; i++) {
    if(bag[i].equals(a)) {
        bag[i] = bag[bag.length-1];
        bag = Arrays.copyOf (bag, bag.length - 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] removeElements(String[] input) {
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

String deleteValue = "somevalue";
for(String item : input)
    if(!deleteValue .equals(item))
        result.add(item);

return result.toArray(input);
}
```

This is one method you can fit this into your program.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot decrease the size of an array. okay no problem! you can create your own data structure which supports that right?
Now, create a class named say MyArray with functions like increaseLenght(int) and decreseLength(int). Try it if you want to, will be fun for sure..

Answer (score -1):

You cannot reduce the size of an array. Arrays are fixed length. What you can do is have a variable that indicates how many entries of the array you are using. This is what you are doing with `numElements`. The standard class `ArrayList` is implemented like this. The data is kept in an array and a private field `size` is used. With an `ArrayList`, when you remove an element, all the elements to the right are shifted left. However I also like your idea.

I would suggest 2 changes.

1. Make the last element `null` instead. If you are removing the element, why does it still need to be in the array?
2. Use `numElements - 1` rather than `bag.length-1` as the array could be bigger.

With these changes it becomes:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bag.length; i++)
{
    if(bag[i].equals(a))
    {
        bag[i] = bag[numElements-1];
        bag[numElements-1] = null;
        numElements--;
        break;
    }
}
```